# S3 PUT Upload file with PreSignedURL using URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, urlsession

Im trying to upload an image file to S3 using PresignedURL, but for some reason the uploaded file turns into 1 small square image(it's a 200 success). I have no problem when I do it in POSTMAN.
So far I tried to replicate the POSTMAN headers but no luck.

```
func uploadImage(urlString: String, fileName: String, data: Data, onSuccess: @escaping VoidResult) {
      let session = URLSession.shared

      var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urlString)!)
      urlRequest.httpMethod = "PUT"
      urlRequest.setValue("image/jpeg", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
      urlRequest.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
      urlRequest.setValue("gzip, deflate, br", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept-Encoding")
      urlRequest.setValue("keep-alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
      urlRequest.setValue("PostmanRuntime/7.29.0", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

    var formData = Data()

    formData.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    formData.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"\(fileName)\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
    formData.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg".data(using: .utf8)!)
    formData.append(data)

      session.uploadTask(with: urlRequest, from: formData, completionHandler: { responseData, response, error in
          if error == nil {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              onSuccess()
            }
          }
      }).resume()
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think 2 reasons makes the uploaded file turns into 1 small square image:

1. What is your input body in Postman? Postman will not send file with form-data format if your setting same as below.
   [image]
2. What is your `Content-Length` in header? As I see your header including `Accept`, `Content-Type`, `Agent` without `Content-Length`.
   [image]